# Why is the behavior different for count and unique different for GroupBy objects?

Tags: pandas

I have the following csv file:

```
col_1,col_2
foo,1
foo,1
bar,1
bar,2
baz,1
baz,1
baz,2
baz,2
qux,1
qux,2
qux,3
```

And the following code (together with the outputs)

```
print(df.groupby('col_1').count())
#        col_2
# col_1
# bar        2
# baz        4
# foo        2
# qux        3

print(df.groupby('col_1').nunique())
#        col_1  col_2
# col_1
# bar        1      2
# baz        1      2
# foo        1      1
# qux        1      3
```

With `nunique`, 2 columns are returned: `col_1` and `col_2`. Why is col_1 missing when I call `count`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` & `nunique` are different functions and do different things.

Documentation links for further reading:

- [count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html)
- [nunique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html)

`count` returns the number of *non-NA values* for each series in each group.

`nunique` returns the number of *unique non-NA values* for each series in each group

---

As to why `nunique` is implemented such that the grouping columns are also included, I'm not sure, as that series will trivially always be a series of ones in the `df.groupby(...).nunique()` use case.

In the usual case, the grouping columns are set as index (unless `as_index=False`) is used and not duplicated as columns in the frame.

The behaviour of `count` conforms to the *expected* `groupby apply/agg` semantics and not the other way around.

However, someone did write test for [`nunique`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/377caeb8a85097af21ad72d0f56925ae8d76e429/pandas/tests/groupby/test_function.py#L825) where the expected output also includes the grouping columns as columns for both `as_index=True` & `as_index=False` as you have observed.